# Xcode - Draw Circle Around Centre

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing, core-graphics

I was wondering how to draw a circle around a point taken from a control's positioning.

This is not working as hoped

```
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2, 10.0, 10.0));

CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
```

Comment: How is it not working? It is not drawing the circle?

Comment: Is the lack of a stroke your problem?

Comment: the problem I get is that the circle doesn't centre around the given point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its pretty easy to draw a circle using UIBezierPath. All you need to do is subclass UIView and create UIBezierPath. I have created a example using UIBezierPath :

Create a subclass of UIView called CirecleView. Add following code :

```
#import "CircleView.h"

@implementation CircleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat rectX = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat rectY = self.frame.size.height / 2;
    CGFloat width = 100;
    CGFloat height = 100;
    CGFloat centerX = rectX - width/2;
    CGFloat centerY = rectY - height/2;


    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(centerX, centerY, width, height)];

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}

@end
```

Change your controller's view class to CircleView. Please see below picture.

[image]

Thats it. Run your code to present your controller's view. Following is the output :

[image]

You can down code example from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xg0hfz7t4pulics/DrawCircle.zip)

Comment: the problem I get is that the circle doesn't centre around the given point

Comment: I have edited my code to centre circle. Please give appropriate width and height based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks I managed to figure out the same solution :-) much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to translate to the point first

```
cgContextRef.translateBy(x:circlePoint.x, y:circlePoint.y)
```

Note this is Swift 3,  it may be different in other languages, just search "translate cgcontext"