# An easy way to draw a circle using CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

In questions like [How to draw a smooth circle...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316705/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-with-cashapelayer-and-uibezierpath), [...Draw Circle...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954735/xcode-draw-circle-around-centre) and [...draw filled Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038017/ios-draw-filled-circles) the question and answer is very broad, contains lots of unnecessary steps and the methods used isn't always the easiest to re-create or manage.

What is an easy way to draw a circle and add it to my `UIView`?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

An easy way to draw a circle is to create a `CAShapeLayer` and add a `UIBezierPath`.

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)

```
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer();
circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)).cgPath;
```

After creating the `CAShapeLayer` we set its `path` to be a `UIBezierPath`.

Our `UIBezierPath` then draws a `bezierPathWithOvalInRect`. The `CGRect` we set will effect its size and position.

Now that we have our circle, we can add it to our `UIView` as a `sublayer`.

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

```
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)

```
view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

Our circle is now visible in our `UIView`.

[image: Circle]

If we wish to customise our circle's color properties we can easily do so by setting the `CAShapeLayer`'s `stroke`- and `fill` color.

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

```
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)

```
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor;
```

[image: Circle_wColors]

Additionall properties can be found over at 's documentation on the subject [https://developer.apple.com/.../CAShapeLayer_class/index.html](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer).

Comment: How can I increase the size of the above red border/stroke?

Comment: @RohanSanap you can do so by editing the lineWidth property of the layer

Answer (score 0):

Using CAShapeLayer Class makes drawing easy...
1.Create CAShapeLayer Object
2.Create a Circular path 
3.Set the path to the wanted CAShapeLayer path
4.Add the layer to your view

```
  let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  let center = view.center
  let circulPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

  shapeLayer.path = circulPath.cgPath 
  view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Note That ,here I draw the circle from center of the view. 
You can also set the fill color for your circle like bellow:

```
  shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

for further study you can check on 
[CALayer.com](https://www.calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/22/cashapelayer-in-depth.html)