# Drawing multiple UIImageViews with the same UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to draw a line using multiple `UIImageView` of the same circle image.

I have tried the following:

```
let imageName = "circle.jpg"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    for var i in 0..<100 {
        i += 1
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: i, y: 200, width: 25, height: 25)
        view.addSubview(imageView)

      }
```

This produces one circle at the position `(100, 200)`. This happens because the same `UIImageView` is being added to the subview so it is only updating the position rather than adding a new `UIImageView`. If I create a new `UIImageView` named "imageView1" and add it to the subview, it will create a new circle.

For the purpose of forming a line by overlapping the `UIImageViews` of these circles, manually creating a `UIImageView` for each circle is obviously inefficient.

So, how can I use the same `UIImage` to draw multiple `UIImageViews`?
Any other suggestions on how I can get around accomplishing this?

Comment: try by adding code of for loop in autoreleasepool.(make sure that-only inner code will be inside the pool, but for loop is outside the pool)

Comment: And what's the point of autorelease pool here? It will do literally nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need a circle to form a line like this**

[image]

Well here the code I used for this using `While` loop

```
let imageName = "synergy-many-people-turning-in-gears_gg55375354.jpg"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        var i = 0
        while(i<100)
        {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: i, y: 200, width: 25, height: 25)
            view.addSubview(imageView)
            i = i + 25//Here I set it to the width so that the images don't overlap 
            //you can use any value for the desired effect it just sets the location 
            //of X-Co-ordinate where the next image would be added
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would quickly try out something like this (didn't test it though):

> var imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple UIImageViews is the thing you need to do. If this will be to slow (btw you should place your image inside assets catalogue to allow caching and improve performance), you should switch to lower level api. Check [iOS - An easy way to draw a circle using CAShapeLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442516/ios-an-easy-way-to-draw-a-circle-using-cashapelayer)
And, btw, why do you change i variable inside loop, this is very bad practice